# PUT survey results on SharePoint 2013

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, survey

I have a custom survey form build in jquery mobile. How can I PUT the json string with results on the Sharepoint server?

```
var jsonstring = JSON.stringify(form_data);
```

It doesn't really matter if each survey response creates a new file or whatever. I don't know what options are available. The string is not the same for each answered survey. Adding the survey string to a txt file would be fine.
Thank you!